# Sorting a list in bash 1

Tags: bash, awk

i have in test.idx many text and i will all lines with:

```
# alt: Spanish
# alt: German
# alt: Englisch
```

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
results=$(cat /home/test.idx | grep "# alt:" | awk '{print $3}')
echo "$results"
```

output is among themselves:

```
Spanish
German
English
```

how can output one after the other? :

```
Spanish German English
```

Regards

Comment: `awk '/^# alt:/{printf "%s%s", (NR==1?"":" "), $3} END{print ""}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, pipe into paste:

```
awk '{print $3}' | paste -s -
```

Another, use printf instead of print:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $3} END { print "" }'
```

Comment: huburt achmet, and when i want output seperator ,? to output  Spanish, German, English

Comment: Awk can handle this without a pipe to paste but that particular awk-only script will add a trailing blank at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/# alt:/{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? OFS : ""), $NF} END{print ""}' file
Spanish German Englisch
```

and in response to your comment under @jas's answer:

```
$ awk -v OFS=', ' '/# alt:/{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? OFS : ""), $NF} END{print ""}' file
Spanish, German, Englisch
```

This only works for one-word languages, if you have to handle "Ancient Greek" for example then you'd need a slightly different solution, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
# alt: Spanish
# alt: Ancient Greek
# alt: Englisch
# alt: Upper Sorbian

$ awk -v OFS=', ' 'sub(/^# alt: */,""){printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? OFS : ""), $0} END{print ""}' file
Spanish, Ancient Greek, Englisch, Upper Sorbian
```

Comment: hmm, dont work, results=$(cat /home/test.idx | grep "# alt:" | awk -v OFS=', ' '/# alt:/{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? OFS : ""), $NF} END{print ""}') result is ", English" and with results=$(cat /home/test.idx  | awk -v OFS=', ' '/# alt:/{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? OFS : ""), $NF} END{print ""}') is same result ", English"

Comment: with comand awk -v OFS=', ' '/# alt:/{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? OFS : ""), $NF} END{print ""}' /home/test.idx  is output , English

Comment: its a problem that another text between is it? wtih only # alt: ... in all lines working this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772568/1745001 for more information on this issue.